# Meaning of reconcile in the given context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In Dostoevsky's "*Notes from the Underground*", the author says, and I quote :

> Our romantic understands everything, sees everything and sees it often
>   far more clearly than our most positive, practical minds. He
>   **reconciles** himself to nothing and no one, but at the same time will
>   not spurn anything;....

What is the meaning of the word **reconcile** in the last sentence?

Comment: Well, I think that it's a bad translation of the original text in Russian. I've found a different translation in English and another different translation in Spanish (my native language) for that sentence and they didn't mention the word "reconcile". But I don't speak Russian so I can´t explain the original text's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find this exact passage you quoted, but there is another version which seems to be more thoroughly translated.

> The properties of our romantic are to understand everything, to see everything, and to see often incomparably more clearly than our very most positive minds do; **not to be reconciled with anyone or anything**, but at the same time not to spurn anything;

As Collins Dictionary defines it, *to be reconciled with someone* means *to become friendly with them again after a quarrel or disagreement*.

His following thoughts make it more clear.

> He's a broad man, our romantic, and the foremost knave of all our knaves, I can assure you of that . . . even from experience. Naturally, all this is so if the romantic is intelligent. That is – what am I saying! – the romantic is always intelligent;

Our romantic is independent.

He is smart enough not to rely on the outside world and its greatly changeable components.

He is careful. He won't reunite with those who once deceived him.

Answer (score 1):

I think you speak about this excerpt

> Свойства нашего романтика — это все понимать, все видеть и видеть
>   часто несравненно яснее, чем видят самые положительнейшие наши умы; ни
>   с кем и ни с чем не примиряться, но в то же время ничем и не брезгать;

IMHO the most appropriate word in the context of the current days is the word **tolerate**.

> He is not **tolerated** to anyone or anything...

Comment: Having read the Spanish translation, I agree with you that "tolerate" may be a better one than "reconcile" translation but I think that your sentence in English should be: "He doesn't tolerate anyone nor anything". Your sentece is in the passive voice and it doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: @RubioRic you are absolutly right. I am native Russian and English is still my Waterloo :)

Comment: I'm Spanish, I know the feeling :-)